# Removing rows whose elements appear less than a certain number

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a csv file, size around 50Mb. The data is 986132 by 3 matrix of the following form.

`data={{a1,b1,1},{a1,b2,1},{a1,b3,1},{a1,b4,1},{a2,b1,1},{a2,b5,1},{a2,b6,1},{a3,b1,1},{a3,b2,1},{a3,b6,1},{a3,b7,1},...{a3012,b1423,1}}`

The third column is always 1 and there is no pattern between a's and b's.

In the matrix form of `data`, I focus on the second column (b's) and want to remove all the rows that has b$i$ that appears less than a certain number. Say it's 10.

So, for example, if b10, b31, b412 each appears less than 10 times in `data`, I want remove all the rows that contain b11, b31 and b412.

How can I do this? I've tried to convert it to a pivot table and sort it by the number of each b, but my computer can't process it maybe because of the memory limitation..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make some fake data:

```
SeedRandom[10]; numOccurrences = 5;
data = Table[{RandomInteger[{0, 100}], RandomInteger[{1, 100}], 1}, 100];
```

Group the data by the value of b, then select only those values of b for which at least `numOccurrences` instances are present, then take the values of the resulting association and flatten them back into the desired shape:

```
Select[Length[#] >= numOccurrences &]@ GroupBy[#[[2]] &]@ data;
Values[%]~Flatten~1

(* Out: 
 {{83, 1, 1}, {33, 1, 1}, {27, 1, 1}, {12, 1, 1}, {74, 1, 1}}
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

To generate `data` (with `a[i]` instead of `ai` but the principle is unchanged):

```
SeedRandom[2020];
n = 20;
indexA = RandomInteger[{1, 4}, n];
indexB = RandomInteger[{1, 4}, n];
data = Table[{a[indexA[[i]]], b[indexB[[i]]], 1}, {i, n}]

(* {{a[1], b[4], 1}, {a[1], b[2], 1}, {a[1], b[2], 1}, {a[1], b[4], 
  1}, {a[4], b[4], 1}, {a[1], b[4], 1}, {a[3], b[2], 1}, {a[4], b[3], 
  1}, {a[4], b[1], 1}, {a[3], b[3], 1}, {a[1], b[3], 1}, {a[4], b[3], 
  1}, {a[4], b[1], 1}, {a[4], b[4], 1}, {a[4], b[4], 1}, {a[2], b[2], 
  1}, {a[1], b[4], 1}, {a[2], b[1], 1}, {a[4], b[3], 1}, {a[2], b[4], 
  1}} *)
```

Then, store variablesn that appear less than `min` times  in the second colum, and select rows whose second value in not in the list of bad indices `badB`:

```
min = 5;
badB = Select[Tally[data[[All, 2]]], #[[2]] < min &][[All, 1]]
Select[data, MemberQ[badB, #[[2]]] == False &]

(* {{a[1], b[4], 1}, {a[1], b[4], 1}, {a[4], b[4], 1}, {a[1], b[4], 
1}, {a[4], b[4], 1}, {a[4], b[4], 1}, {a[1], b[4], 1}, {a[2], b[4], 
1}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[pick]
pick = Pick[#, 
    Developer`ToPackedArray @ UnitStep[(Counts[#[[All, 2]]] /@ #[[All, 2]]) - #2], 1] &;
```

Using `data` from MarcoB's answer:

```
SeedRandom[10];
data = Table[{RandomInteger[{0, 100}], RandomInteger[{1, 100}], 1}, 100];
pick[data, 5]
```

> ```
>  {{83, 1, 1}, {33, 1, 1}, {27, 1, 1}, {12, 1, 1}, {74, 1, 1}}
> ```

**Note:** This approach preserves the ordering of kept rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = 
 {{10, 10, 1}, {7, 9, 1}, {6, 6, 1}, {10, 1, 1}, {10, 6, 1}, 
  {7, 9, 1}, {6, 9, 1}, {7, 5, 1}, {0, 8, 1}, {6, 2, 1}};
```

Using `GatherBy`

```
Join @@ Select[Length[#] >= 2 &] @ GatherBy[list, #[[2]] &]
```

{{7, 9, 1}, {7, 9, 1}, {6, 9, 1}, {6, 6, 1}, {10, 6, 1}}

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{10, 10, 1}, {7, 9, 1}, {6, 6, 1}, {10, 1, 1}, {10, 6, 1},
        {7, 9, 1}, {6, 9, 1}, {7, 5, 1}, {0, 8, 1}, {6, 2, 1}};
```

---

Using `SortBy` and `SplitBy`:

```
Cases[s : {_, __} :> Splice@s]@SplitBy[SortBy[list, #[[2]] &], #[[2]] &]

(*{{6, 6, 1}, {10, 6, 1}, {6, 9, 1}, {7, 9, 1}, {7, 9, 1}}*)
```